# Custom route for 'news' resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource in a Rails 3.2 app called "news". I know it is not the best name to use for a resource but I'd prefer not to change it.

I have an issue with the routing since new_news_path doesn't work.

How can I define a custom route for the new action? something like unused_news_path for news#new?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `routes.rb`:

```
match "unused" => "news#new"
```

When you do a `rake routes | grep unused`, you will get the following output:

```
unused /unused(.:format) news#new
```

So you now can use `unused_path` on your views and controller to get to the correspondent action.

Comment: Thanks for your help and Sorry for my late reply